# Python: open cmd and stream text output

Tags: python, cmd

I want to open a new cmd window and stream some text output (logs) while my python script is running (this is basically to check where I am in the script)

I can't find w way to do it and keep it open and stream my output.

Here is what I have now:

```
import os
p = os.popen("start cmd", mode='w')

def log_to_cmd(process, message):
    p.write(message)

for i in range(10):
    log_to_cmd(p, str(i))
```

And I want to get 0 to 9 output on the same cmd window already open.
Thanks a lot for any suggestion.

Comment: Show what you have so far, please. It's not possible to help you to fix something where there is nothing to fix.

Comment: updated @DawidFerenczy, sorry for the missing details

Comment: Have a look at the Python `cmd` module. https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html

Answer (score 0):

use [Baretail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/) this software allows you to stream logs.

If you want to stick to cmd shell I'd suggest installing something like [GNU Utilities for Win32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/). It has most favourites, including tail. `tail` which allows you to open file like a log veiwer .

Comment: Yes I want to stick to cmd, and I can't install anything else